# Method of Differences/Partial fractions with factorials

Tags: factorial, partial-fractions

By first expressing $\frac{1}{r!(r+2)}$ in the form $\frac{A}{(r+2)!} + \frac{B}{(r+1)!}$, find $\sum\limits_{r}^n \frac{1}{r!(r+2)}$. Struggling to do the partial fractions to begin.

Answer (score 3):

One way is:
$$\frac{1}{r!(r+2)}=\frac{r+1}{(r+2)!}=\frac{r+2-1}{(r+2)!}=\frac1{(r+1)!}-\frac1{(r+2)!}.$$
And it results in telescoping difference.

Comment: Thanks very much I believe this is the way it should have been done. In hindsight partial fractions seems wrong!!

Comment: In general, you should equate as follows: $\frac{1}{r!(r+2)}=\frac{r+1}{(r+2)!}=\frac{A}{(r+2)!} + \frac{B}{(r+1)!} = \frac{A+B(r+2)}{(r+2)!} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}B=1 \\ A+2B=1 \end{cases} \Rightarrow A=-1, B=1$.